# Where are the commercials coming from in itunes and how to remove them?

Tags: itunes

I updated iTunes to v.11.0.1, and now when I play my music from my hard drive, randomly in between songs, there are commercials from 1.FM. This is very annoying!

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Wow, this is really weird. I have never encountered something like this in iTunes. Do you also listen to radio streams in iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

Re-install the iTunes because it's not a normal thing to be happening